# Solr 4.2 EmbeddedSolrServer can not load existing index data

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I'm extending Solr's **AbstractSolrTestCase** for unit testing.

I have existing 'schema.xml', 'solrconfig.xml' and index data. I can start an embedded solr server to load existing collection and its data. Then test searching doc in solr.

Those test files(solr conf and data index) still work with Solr 4.2. I can launch a solr server in command line, and successfully query doc via admin page.

> java -Dsolr.solr.home=/somewhere/testdata/solr -jar start.jar

However this way does not work any more after adapting to Solr 4.2.1. After some investigating, I found it looks like the index data is not loaded by solr's EmbeddedSolrServer.

Does anybody know how to let EmbeddedSolrServer load the existing index data?

I'm using below code to create embedded server for unit testing. In below code I'm using index data from solr official example.

```
public class IntegrationSolrTest2 extends AbstractSolrTestCase {
    private static final String CORE_NAME = "collection1";
    private static File solrTestHome = new File(
            "/Users/kane/Downloads/solr-4.2.1/example/solr");
    private static File confHome = new File(solrTestHome, CORE_NAME + "/conf");
    private static File indexFile = new File(confHome.getParentFile(),
            "data/index");
    private SolrServer server;

    @Override
    public String getSolrHome() {
        return solrTestHome.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    final String configFile = new File(confHome, "solrconfig.xml")
            .getAbsolutePath();

    // Creates a container based on infos needed to create one core
    static class Initializer extends CoreContainer.Initializer {
        String coreName;
        String dataDirectory;
        SolrConfig solrConfig;
        IndexSchema indexSchema;

        public Initializer(String coreName, String dataDirectory,
                SolrConfig solrConfig, IndexSchema indexSchema) {
            if (coreName == null)
                coreName = CoreContainer.DEFAULT_DEFAULT_CORE_NAME;
            this.coreName = coreName;
            this.dataDirectory = dataDirectory;
            this.solrConfig = solrConfig;
            this.indexSchema = indexSchema;
        }

        public String getCoreName() {
            return coreName;
        }

        @Override
        public CoreContainer initialize() {
            CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(new SolrResourceLoader(
                    SolrResourceLoader.locateSolrHome())) {
                {
                    hostPort = System.getProperty("hostPort");
                    hostContext = "solr";
                    defaultCoreName = coreName;
                    initShardHandler(null);
                    initZooKeeper(System.getProperty("zkHost"), 10000);
                }
            };
            LogWatcher<?> logging = new JulWatcher("test");
            logging.registerListener(new ListenerConfig(), container);
            container.setLogging(logging);

            CoreDescriptor dcore = new CoreDescriptor(container, coreName,
                    solrConfig.getResourceLoader().getInstanceDir());
            dcore.setConfigName(solrConfig.getResourceName());
            dcore.setSchemaName(indexSchema.getResourceName());
            SolrCore core = new SolrCore(coreName, dataDirectory, solrConfig,
                    indexSchema, dcore);
            container.register(coreName, core, false);

            // TODO: we should be exercising the *same* core container
            // initialization code, not equivalent code!
            if (container.getZkController() == null
                    && core.getUpdateHandler().getUpdateLog() != null) {
                // always kick off recovery if we are in standalone mode.
                core.getUpdateHandler().getUpdateLog().recoverFromLog();
            }
            return container;
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solrConfig = TestHarness.createConfig(solrTestHome.getAbsolutePath(),
                CORE_NAME, configFile);
        h = new TestHarness(IntegrationSolrTest2.CORE_NAME, new Initializer(
                IntegrationSolrTest2.CORE_NAME, indexFile.getParentFile()
                        .getAbsolutePath(), solrConfig, new IndexSchema(
                        solrConfig, getSchemaFile(), null)));
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(h.getCoreContainer(), h.getCore()
                .getName());
        h.getCoreContainer().reload(CORE_NAME);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        h.getCoreContainer().shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void searchAll() throws Exception {
        h.reload();
        SolrQuery params = new SolrQuery();
        params.setQuery("*:*");
        QueryResponse response = server.query(params);
        final SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        assertTrue("Not search the expected goods!", results.getNumFound() > 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you check http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200910.mbox/%3c25818657.post@talk.nabble.com%3e and http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200910.mbox/%3cPine.LNX.4.64.0910131044210.19912@radix.cryptio.net%3e ?

Comment: @kamaci, I did put my index files under '<core instance dir>/data/index'. I also tried to use above test code to load index created by solr 4.2.1 official example, it also doesn't work. However I can use EmbeddedSolrServer to load existing index when using solr 3.6.

Comment: you say: "However this way does not work any more after adapting to Solr 4.2.1" do you get any error?

Comment: @kamaci, there is no error when starting EmbeddedSolrServer. But I can't query any doc from it. You can see I have a very simple test case **searchAll** to query all docs from Solr, but looks like there is no doc in solr core(I suspect the existing index not loaded by solr) after migrating Solr to 4.2.1.